# Readthedocs local server stuck on Triggered state during build

Tags: python-2.7, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I have installed a [local instance of Readthedocs server](http://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), but anytime I try to build a github repository **the app gets stuck in the Triggered state!**.

[image]

There is no errors or exceptions, just regular info messages:

```
[25/Apr/2017 14:21:11] INFO [readthedocs.projects.utils:81] Running: 'ln -nsf /var/www/my-project/user_builds/test1/rtd-builds/latest /var/www/my-project/public_web_root/test1/en/latest' [/var/www/my-project]
[25/Apr/2017 14:21:11] INFO [readthedocs.projects.tasks:844] (Build) [test1:] Updating static metadata
```

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could be related to an open issue: https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2471

Answer (score 0):

so I had this problem, and there seems to be a lot of different things that could cause it, because I've seen various postings about it on different forums however none of the solutions posted helped me. The only posting i have book marked is [this github issue](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/1762).

for me I found that the documentation would build if I ran the command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, but would be stuck in a triggered state if I used my computers ip address; the solution was to use the above command but to add the following to readthedocs/settings/local_settings.py :

```
import os

# Set this to the root domain where this RTD installation will be running
PRODUCTION_DOMAIN = os.getenv('RTD_PRODUCTION_DOMAIN', '10.x.x.x:8000')

# Enable private Git doc repositories
ALLOW_PRIVATE_REPOS = True
```

best of luck.